# Secret generation in redmine installation fails with error in mysql2/mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, mysql2

I am trying to install redmine 2.3.x on my Debian vServer. I already managed to build ruby from source and installed gems, rails and the apache passenger module. It should work until that point. I used the turotial at domainfactory: http://www.df.eu/de/service/df-faq/cloudserver/anleitungen/ruby-on-rails-installieren-debian-ubuntu/ .

After that I downloaded and extracted the redmine application as described here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Installation-procedure. I created a mysql account and database, made a copy of the config/database.yml.example -> config/database.yml and filled in the correct values.

After that I installed bundler with

```
gem install bundler
```

And did go on with preparing the environment:

```
bundle install --without development test
```

All these commands did succeed.

After that I wanted to generate the secret token with the fallowing command:

```
rake generate_secret_token
```

The execution was interrupted with the fallowing message:

```
 # rake generate_secret_token --trace
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/var/www/potato/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/www/potato/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I was trying to resolve this by checking versions and installed gems.

Ruby: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
Rails: Rails 3.2.13
Gems: 1.8.25
Redmine: 2.3.3

I verified with `gem list --local` that the gem "mysql2" is installed.

gem "mysql": mysql2 (0.3.13)

As the problem seems to rely on this, I tried reinstalling the package, but this did not help.

What did I wrong here?

Thanks in advance,
Sebastian Büttner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this error happens if you don't have the following package installed in your system (at least on Debian 9). So run command:

`apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: This topic is a few yours old by now, but I resolved it the same way, so this fixed it for me too. Marked as solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. try `bundle exec rake generate_secret_token`
2. (if #1 does not help) Check if mysql2 is presented in output list for `bundle list` (it is different with `gem list`!). Be careful that redmine [install DB adapter according to](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.3-stable/Gemfile#L47) your settings in `database.yml` (but I think you install it correctly)

Comment: Thanks for your answere. Unfortunately both solutions did not work. (1.) Genreated the same output as executed without `bundle exec` and  (2.) gave me a mysql (0.3.13) entry within `bundle list`.

Comment: maybe this will help `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake generate_secret_token`. The reason: you have setup gems from Production group but running rake task in default env (if it is not set then it is development) system looks for gems from development group

Comment: and check that your `database.yml` has `mysql2` adapter for production DB

Comment: I've tried what you said, but it did not work for me. The error remains the same with the same stacktrace. I did try a fresh setup and ended up in the same situation. I also checked my `config/database.yml` , it does contain a section for productive environment with mysql2.

Comment: I don't have really good ideas any more. You can try to install one of the ruby manager (I suggest [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)) and work through it.

Comment: It turned out I had a version conflict with between the software. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Please, check if you have necessary VC runtime installed. Please, check the VC runtime dll version, your mysql vendor dll is dependent upon.

Comment: Please check first sentence of question. Its a Debian/Linux Installation. Not a msvc Environment.

Comment: Senile dementia